# substring finding from a string

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, suffix-tree

Input: string S = AAGATATGATAGGAT.

Output: Maximal repeats such as GATA (as in positions 3 and 8), GAT (as in position 3, 8 and 13) and so on...

- A maximal repeat is a substring t occurs k>1 times in S, and if t is extended to left or right, it will occur less than k times.
- An internal node’s leaf descendants are suffixes, each of which has a left character.
- If the left characters of all leaf descendants are not all identical, it’s called a “left-diverse” node.
- Maximal repeats is left-diverse internal nodes.

Overall idea:

- Build a suffix tree and then do a DFS (depth first search) on the tree
- For each leaf, label it with its left character
- For each internal node:
- If at least one child is labelled with *, then label it with *
- Else if its children’s labels are diverse, label with *.
- Else then all children have same label, copy it to current node

Is the above idea is correct? How does the pseudo-code to be? Then I can try to write programming myself.

Comment: @Bryan, yup..trying to write out programming code..i would like to ask for some help in pseudo-code..then i will try to write out myself the whole programming...

Comment: DFS stands for Depth First Search, not Deep Force Search.

Comment: @rock: figuring out the algorithm (problem solving in general) is probably the most important part of a programmer's work. Coding is more or less a mechanical activity.

Comment: Good question, and more importantly, *valid* question. Contrast this with other “plz send teh codez” homework requests. I don’t know why people get their knickers in a twist whenever someone has a homework question here. +1 from me for an interesting problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your idea is good, but with a suffix tree you can do something even easier.

> Let T be the suffix tree of your sequence .
>
> Let x be a node in T, T_x is the subtree of T with root x.
>
> Let N_x be the number of leaf in T_x
>
> Let  word(x) be the word created by traversing T from root to node x
>
> Now using the definition of a suffix tree we get :
>
> **Number of repeats of word(x) =  N_x  and the position of this words are the label of each leaf**

The algorithm for this would be a basic tree traversal, for each node in the tree calculate N_x, if N_x > 2 add this to your result (if you want the position too you can add the label of each leaf)

**Pseudo code :**

> **input :**
>
> mySequence
>
> **output:**
>
> Result (list of word that repeat with count and position)
>
> **Algorithm :**
>
> T = suffixTree(mySequence)
>
> For each internal node X in T:
>
> ```
>   T_X = subTree(T)
>   N_X = Number of lead (T_X)
>   if N_X >=2 :
>   Result .add ( [word(X), N_X , list(label of leafs)] )
> ```
>
> return Result

**Example :**

let's take the wikipedia example for suffix trees : **"BANANA"** :

[image]

we get :

```
N_A = 3 so "A" repeats 3 times in position {1,3,5}
N_N=2  so "N" repeats 2 times  in position {2,4}
N_NA=2  so "NA" repeats 2 times in position {2,4}
```

---

I found this paper that seems to treat your problem the same way you're doing, so yes I think your method is write :

[Spelling approximate repeated or common motifs using a suffix tree](http://pbil.univ-lyon1.fr/members/sagot/htdocs/publications/latin/latin.html)

> **Extract**
>
> We present in this paper two algorithms. The first one extracts
>   repeated motifs from a sequence defined over an alphabet Sigma. For
>   instance, Sigma may be equal to {A, C, G, T} and the sequence
>   represent an encoding of a DNA macromolecule. The motifs searched
>   correspond to words over the same alphabet which occur a minimum
>   number q of times in the sequence with at most e mismatches each time
>   (q is called the quorum constraint).[...]

You can download it and have a look at it , the author gives pseudo code for your algorithm.

Hope this helps

Comment: @TomasT. I didn't draw it this time :D. Took it from the wikipedia page on suffix trees.